# While automating script using selenium webdriver ,`.isDisplayed()` command is not working in `if else` statement

Tags: selenium

While automating script using selenium webdriver ,`.isDisplayed()` command is not working in **if else statement**.
If the condition is true under if statement, then it is working fine. But if the condition is not true, the code is not moving to else statement.

```
package module17;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;

public class Dice {
static WebDriver driver = null;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\Automation Software\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver_update.exe");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        //driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.get("http://www.dice.com/");
        Thread.sleep(15000);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@alt='Close']")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='search-field-keyword']")).sendKeys("Selenium WebDriver");
        WebElement Place =driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@placeholder='Location']"));
        Place.clear();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[contains(text(),'Find Tech Jobs')]")).click();
        WebElement PageNumber = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='dice_paging_top']//*[contains(text(),'2')]"));
        int i=2;
        while(i<=44)
        {
            try
                {
                    if(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='dice_paging_top']//*[contains(text(),'"+i+"')]")).isDisplayed()  )
                        {
                            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='dice_paging_top']//*[contains(text(),'"+i+"')]")).click();
                            Thread.sleep(5000);
                            i= i+5;
                        }
                    else if(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='dice_paging_top']//a[@title='Go to next page']")).isDisplayed() )
                        {
                            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='dice_paging_top']//a[@title='Go to next page']")).click();
                        }
                    else
                        {
                            driver.quit();
                        }
                }  
            catch (Exception e)
                {
                    System.out.println("Exception");
                }

        }   
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually `isDisplayed()`is working fine. Issue is in your looping. In first if condition you have incremented value with `i+5` So the value 7 not matched in xpath in next iteration that's why it was moving in Exception.

You need to manage your if else conditions in try catch block . Replace below looping code and try

```
int i=5;
while(i<=44)
{
    try
    {
        if(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='dice_paging_top']//*[contains(text(),'"+i+"')]")).isDisplayed()  )
        {
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='dice_paging_top']//*[contains(text(),'"+i+"')]")).click();
            Thread.sleep(5000);
            i+=5;
        }

     }catch(Exception e)
       {
            try
            {
                 if(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='dice_paging_top']//a[@title='Go to next page']")).isDisplayed() )
                 {
                     driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='dice_paging_top']//a[@title='Go to next page']")).click();
                 }
            }
            catch(Exception e2)
            {
                driver.quit();
           }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the second iteration I value set to 7, with this value of I in xpath, element is not exist on the current page.If the element is not exist on the page then drive.findElement will throw NoSuchElementException so it won't be entered into your elseif block at all I modified your code accordingly(Update your solution below and provided my solution at last).

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class Dice {
static WebDriver driver = null;
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\Automation Software\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver_update.exe");
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    //driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.get("http://www.dice.com/");
    Thread.sleep(15000);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@alt='Close']")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='search-field-keyword']")).sendKeys("Selenium WebDriver");
    WebElement Place =driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@placeholder='Location']"));
    Place.clear();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[contains(text(),'Find Tech Jobs')]")).click();
    WebElement PageNumber = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='dice_paging_top']//*[contains(text(),'2')]"));
    int i=2;
    while(i<=44)
    {
        try
        {
            if(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='dice_paging_top']//*[contains(text(),'"+i+"')]")).isDisplayed()  )
            {
                driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='dice_paging_top']//*[contains(text(),'"+i+"')]")).click();
                Thread.sleep(5000);
                i+=1;
            }
        }  
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            try{
                if(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='dice_paging_top']//a[@title='Go to next page']")).isDisplayed() )
                {
                    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='dice_paging_top']//a[@title='Go to next page']")).click();
                    i+=1;
                }
            }
            catch(Exception e1){
                driver.quit();
            }
          }

       }   
      }   
    }
```

If you goal is to went through all job posts then below is my shorten code.

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class Dice {
  static WebDriver driver = null;
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\Automation Software\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver_update.exe");
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.get("http://www.dice.com/");
    Thread.sleep(15000);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@alt='Close']")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='search-field-keyword']")).sendKeys("Selenium WebDriver");
    WebElement Place =driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@placeholder='Location']"));
    Place.clear();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[contains(text(),'Find Tech Jobs')]")).click();
    while(true)
    {
        List<WebElement> nextPage = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='dice_paging_top']//a[@title='Go to next page']"));
        if(nextPage.size()>0&&nextPage.get(0).isEnabled()){
            nextPage.get(0).click();
        }
        else{
            break;
        }
    }
    driver.quit();
   }   
  }
```

Try it and let me know if you have any queries

Comment: Wrong! If element exists and it doesn't displayed then it returns false. It will throw the error only if element doesn't exist. This problem can be solved in more efficient way, but no one still haven't given the correct answer.

Comment: @Gopal we can solve it in more efficient way but i fixed the code thats it. if element not exists in the page then  driver.findelement itself will throw an exception i.e NoSuchElementException. Correct me if i am worng.

Comment: Yes I agree that's what I am saying as well, but isDisplayed doesn't throw the error if element present and not visible, it returns false, but your reply mainly says it throws the error, that's wrong.

Comment: Actually I am trying to convey the same but it conveyed wrong, I updated the answer with correct text.

Comment: Your modified explanation doesn't include anything about isDisplayed function, findElement will throw the error if it doesn't find element is part of the story here, but that's not a main story.